# Svelte add param to derived state and keep its reactivity

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

In this example, `$derivedValue` is reactive; if `myArray` is changed at index 3, it will change automatically, too.

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import { myArray, derivedValue } from './store';
</script>

<h1>{$myArray}</h1>
<h1>{$derivedValue}</h1>
```

store.js

```
import {derived, writable} from 'svelte/store';

export const myArray = writable([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
export const derivedValue = derived(myArray, value => value[3]);
```

I would like to create a reactive getter, which looks like this:

```
export const derivedValue = index => derived(myArray, value => value[index]);
```

Of course, in this case `derivedValue` is a function and is not subscribable anymore. Is there a way to create such a subscribable reactive derived value with a parameter?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproductible example by using a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.42.4) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`derivedValue` will indeed be a function, but it returns a store. You would use it like this:

```html
<script>
    import { myArray, derivedValue } from './store';
    const first = derivedValue(0);
</script>

<h1>{$myArray}</h1>
<h1>{$first}</h1>
```

If you want this index to be reactive as well, you could reactively generate the store:

```js
$: current = derivedValue(index)
```

and still use it as a regular store: `$current`